# dropdown list of html with $variable giving wrong result in display

Tags: html, laravel

I am trying to make dropdown-list in html/bootstrap which is result me wrong designed output. let me share what i have done in code.

**controller code :**

```
        $countries = Country::select('country','id')->get();
```

HTML code:

```html
                            <div class="form-group">
                                Country:<select name="country_id" id="exchange" class="form-control"  for="id">
                                    <option value="" id="fid"></option>
                                    @foreach($countries as  $key=>$val )
                                        <option value="{{ $key}}">{{  $val }}</option>
                                    @endforeach
                                </select>
                            </div>
```

problem you can see in below output:

[here is output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O9PY2.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try my snippet, because `$country` in the loop holds a model object from `Country`

```
<div class="form-group">
    Country:<select name="country_id" id="exchange" class="form-control"  for="id">
        <option value="" id="fid"></option>
        @foreach($countries as  $country )
            <option value="{{ $country->id }}">{{  $country->country }}</option>
        @endforeach
    </select>
</div>
```

Comment: This is working as expected, ... can you suggest me how to make `collective laravel` form ?

Comment: What do you mean by `collective`?

Comment: that is laravel : `Collective\Html\Form`

Answer (score 0):

Change your controller code as follow

```
$countries = Country::pluck('country', 'id');
```

Comment: Which version you are using?